# Ext.DomQuery.select Issue if selector contains comma

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3, extjs4.2

I am trying to Query a node from xml depending on selector , and domquery is throwing error if my select on is having comma in it !

Issue in : **Ext.DomQuery.select("root/I[a='abc,d']", resp.responseXML);**

Below is my sample code :

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'sample.xml',
        success : function (resp, e) {
            //var a = Ext.DomQuery.select("root/I[a='abc']", resp.responseXML);
            var b = Ext.DomQuery.select("root/I[@a='abc']", resp.responseXML);
            var c = Ext.DomQuery.select("root/I[a='abc'd']", resp.responseXML);
            var d = Ext.DomQuery.select("root/I[a='abc@d']", resp.responseXML);
//All the above are working fine

//Below line is not at all working
            var d = Ext.DomQuery.select("root/I[a='abc,d']", resp.responseXML);
// throwing error as : 'Error parsing selector, parsing failed at "' + path + '"'; at line 1126 in ext-all-debug.js 

        },
        failure : function (resp, e) {
            debugger;
        }
    });
});
```

And my xml is as follows :

```
<root>
    <I a="abc"/>
    <I a="abc'd"/>
    <I a="abc@d"/>
    <I a="abc,d"/>
    <I a="abc!d"/>
</root>
```

I have used this selector lot of places in my code and this is just a sample. Always this selector ( here **"abc,d"** )  will be coming from a variable and it is dynamic. No one knows when comma comes and when not. how to handle this issue ? Is there any fix for this ?

Comment: What version of ExtJS are you using? I just tried this in 4.2, and it worked fine. By the way, it doesn't make sense to tag this as both extjs3 and extjs4. Those two are VERY different from each other.

Comment: This piece of code has no change for any version of ExtJS. So I tagged for both. 

And I tried with even extjs 4.2.1 too. 
It throws error as : "Error parsing selector. Parsing failed at \"[a=\'abc\""                      In ext-all-debug.js at line :   throw new Ext.Error(err);   (line number 6879)

Answer (score 0):

This wont work. I have tried a lot. Finally decided to use **start with** in domquery and traverse the resulted array to find the exact match. See the following sample

```
var d = Ext.DomQuery.select("root/I[a^='abc']", resp.responseXML);
var selectedNode = null;
for(var index = 0; index < d.length; index++){
    if(d[index].getAttribute('a') == 'abc,d'){
        selectedNode = d[index];
    }
}
console.log(selectedNode);
```

If you want the exact match is in an array, please use the following sample

```
var selectedNode = new Array();
for(var index = 0; index < d.length; index++){
    if(d[index].getAttribute('a') == 'abc,d'){
        selectedNode.push(d[index]);
    }
}
console.log(selectedNode);
```